# How to let debezium start reading binlog from the last row

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, binlog

I'm trying to let Debezium start reading the binlog from the bottom of the file directly.
Could someone help in this matter please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the docs](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/#connector-properties) it looks like you can use `snapshot.mode=schema_only`:

> If you don’t need the topics to contain a consistent snapshot of the data but only need them to have the changes since the connector was started, you can use the `schema_only` option, where the connector only snapshots the schemas (not the data).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ingest from the last position, you can drain the groups by doing this:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic topicName --group groupName --from-beginning
```